# How to add a new operation that will run in a fixed process in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to add a new operation, and it will be used multiple times in the graph. It requires that it will run in the same CPU process when it is called.
How to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Would `with tf.device("cpu:0"): ...` work?

Comment: This is to put the op on cpu0, but still multiple threads may be used.